# IntelliJ opening javadocs in sublime text (instead of browser)

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I'm trying to view javadocs of particular classes using IntelliJ. I can select the token and press shift+F4, or I can use ctrl+Q and then click the up arrow, and it opens the javadocs, but when I do, it opens it in sublime text instead of a browser. This is probably because I have HTML files set to open in sublime text, which is not something I'd like to change if I can avoid it. Is there a way I can explicitly tell IntelliJ to open javadocs in Chrome? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to change the default browser [here](http://i.imgur.com/mVw2Xn1.png)?

Comment: I'll be sure to try that